# Why won't selected form value in HTML Service Pass to Server-Side variable in Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a table that pops up in an HTML UI on command in my Google Sheet file that allows the file's user a look at a summary of orders listed in one of my Google Sheet tabs. The table includes a radio button selection option for each order listed for the user to click on any order they'd like to review in greater detail.  Right now, onClick, the file triggers an alert stating which order has been selected. This tells me everything is working properly, but when I move the alert code out of the client-side HTML  section and to a server-side call via google.script.run, the alert no longer pops up 'onClick'.  Let me know, if you can, where I am going wrong:

```
function htmlOrders() {
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = active.getSheetByName("POHistory");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:K" + lastRow); 
  var data = myRange.getDisplayValues();
  var optionsHTML = "";
  var seenType = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     if(seenType[data[i][0]]) {
       continue;}
   seenType[data[i][0]] = true;
   optionsHTML += "<tr>";
   optionsHTML += "<td><input type='radio' name='selectedPO' value='" + 
 data[i][0] + "'onclick='google.script.run.editPO()';></td>";
   optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][0] + "</td>";
   optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][2] + "</td>";
   optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][1] + "</td>";
   optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][10] + "</td>";
   optionsHTML += "</tr>"
 }
return optionsHTML;} 

function editPO(){
 var whichPO = document.getElementsByName("selectedPO");
 for(i=0 ; i < whichPO.length ; i++) {
  if(whichPO[i].checked)
  {
   alert("you have chosen "+ whichPO[i].value);
  }}}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table name="table" id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Edit?</th>
    <th>PO No.</th>
    <th>Vendor</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
   <?!= htmlOrders(); ?>
</table>
<script>
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Server-side functions must be called via google.script.run. In htmlOrders() function, change the "onClick" handler to:

```
"'onclick='google.script.run.editPO()'
```

As to why it doesn't work - remember that the runtime environment for GAS is NOT your browser, so you don't have access to the Document Object Model (DOM) or BOM (Browser Object Model) from within '.gs' files. The methods and properties you are trying to access belong to the 'window' object in your web browser, which means they are only accessible on the client-side. When you call alert("Hello!") what you are really doing is selecting a property of the global object (in this case, window):

[image]

To see the global object for '.gs' files, try Logger.log(this) and check the output - you'll be surprised. If you need to pass values from server to client side, use success and failure handlers:

```
google.script.run
             .withSuccessHandler(function(res) {             
                   console.log(res);
                 })
             .withFailureHandler(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                 })
             .runServerFunc(req);
```

In conlusion, wrap your client-side JS code in <script> tags and you are good to go.